# How to Display Error message in same page in Trigger(Before Delete)

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

`Trigger.addError` in before delete trigger always shows the error message in a new page.
Instead of showing the error message in new page, I need to show in same standard page.
Is it possible ?

And I have the condition to not delete the record when the active field is checked.

```
trigger OpportunityclosedWon on Opportunity (before Delete) {
    for (Opportunity opp : trigger.Old) {
        if (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
            opp.stagename.adderror('You cannot delete Closed Won Opportunity');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the addError () method on sObject? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError

Comment: also, can you post your full code to help everybody help you better?

Comment: Here is the code:-                                                                                     trigger OpportunityclosedWon on Opportunity (before Delete) { 
   for(Opportunity opp:trigger.Old)
   {
    if(opp.StageName=='Closed Won') 
    {
    opp.stagename.adderror('You cannot delete Closed Won Opportunity');
    }
   }
            

}

Comment: Pasted the code from above comment to question section for clarity in future.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090gBIAQ

> Using standard  page we can have these kind of messages only when we
>   save info  , but we cannot have this for delete actions as the page
>   will be redirected to some predefined page. The only way is to
>   customize the detail page using visual force and there we can have own
>   custom validation.

---

Workaround

You can override Delete button with your javascript custom delete.

Check you condition in JAVASCRIPT and if satisfied then display alert message.
else delete that record.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions would be to override delete button -- create custom JS button with code like this:

```
var data = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Name, Id 
                                    FROM  Account 
                                    WHERE Id = '"+Account.Id+"'"
                                   );
var record = data[0];
if (record){
   var criteria = false;
   //check some criteria
   // if (record.Name = 'To Remove') criteria = true;
   if (criteria){
       result = sforce.connection.delete(record);
       if (!result[0].getBoolean("success")) alert("delete failed");
   }else{
       alert("Can not delete record because of criteria");
   }
}
```

I would recommend to put all criteria in the trigger because if record would be deleted from someone else -- criteria from JS would not work, and just handle error thrown by trigger and display in page.

If you don't like alert methods - you could use custom JS to display error on page - here are some examples: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h9p6AAA.

What else can be done by JS - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_ajax.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the error to the field you want to show for. Example

**Case.Status.adderror('Your error Message');**

Here error message will be displayed on the Status field of the Case record.

Hope this helps.

**Edit :** I have done this thing in my trigger to add error message on status field via trigger if there is no Case Team Member present with the same role.

[image]

Regrds! Ruchi

Comment: nop this will redirect to error page.

Comment: is your trigger on before delete ? looks like you are using update trigger not delete.

Comment: Hmm...ya its on before update....I believed it would had worked on before delete too.

Comment: No it is not working for before Delete .Its redirecting to new Error page

Comment: trigger ChekTriggerOLD on Opportunity (before Delete) {
   for(Opportunity opp:trigger.Old)
   {
    if(opp.StageName=='Closed Won') 
    {
    opp.stagename.adderror('You cannot delete Closed Won Opportunity');
    }
   }
            

}

Comment: Is there any alternative solution

Comment: @sukit We can't do that

Comment: No @Ruchi It won't work with before delete.

Comment: can i use  alert  message in Trigger.so it  will give alert only

Comment: @sukit then you need to create custom javascript button. there you need to check active field is checked or not if checked then delete else dont delete